# Today's date in Outlook Mail Subject (2010/Quick Steps)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

How can I automatically add the current date to the subject of a new Outlook 2010 message? i.e. "Status 2011-09-14" on sending message, from [Quick Steps](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2009/07/27/introducing-quick-steps.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new Macro.
2. Append date to the subject
   `(newItem.Subject = Format(Now, "dd mmmm yyyy") & newItem.Subject)`
3. Create a shortcut to the Macro in the Quick Steps (QAT).

Comment: I believe you mean `newItem.Subject = newItem.Subject & " " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this just within a quickstep. Not in Outlook 2013 either.

One quick way - if you have the ability to install and run it - would be to use AutoHotKey.

This adds macro programming capability to Windows as a whole and you could fairly easily create something that would insert the current date.